# Using MSBuild to create a successful build

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

After building in VS 2012, I am getting the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_222222_256x240.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_454545_256x240.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_888888_256x240.png" because it was not found.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png" because it was not found.
```

For the full contents of the Webapplication.targets file, [i've pasted it here.](http://pastebin.com/sG8sCHn1)

Right before getting these errors, I get something about MICROSOFT.COMMON.TARGETS:

[image]

Some more diagnostic information before and after the errors occur:

```
Task "Copy" (TaskId:211)
  Task Parameter:
      SourceFiles=
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_888888_256x240.png
          Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png (TaskId:211)
  Task Parameter:DestinationFolder=D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\bin\_PublishedWebsites\tzz\Content\themes\base\images\ (TaskId:211)
  Task Parameter:SkipUnchangedFiles=True (TaskId:211)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_222222_256x240.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_454545_256x240.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_888888_256x240.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png" because it was not found. [D:\Builds\2\PACE\vvv Web\src\vvvWebProd\tzz\tzz\tzz.csproj]
Done executing task "Copy" -- FAILED. (TaskId:211)
Done building target "_CopyWebApplicationLegacy" in project "tzz.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:342)
```

**What am I doing wrong, how can I avoid these copy file errors and get this to build?**

Comment: If you browse to that directory, are those `.png` files present in `\Content\themes\base\images` (relative to the project directory)?

Comment: well, the question is where is it referring to? it's a relative path, so i'm not sure where it' referring to

Comment: It's relative to the project directory. In Visual Studio, right-clicking the project and choosing `Open Folder in File Explorer` should take you there.

Comment: yes ideed it's there http://i.imgur.com/3MAhx0J.png

Comment: something weird is happening with TFS, i'm trying to get these: http://i.imgur.com/ISnZH4s.png

Comment: but it says http://i.imgur.com/BX48sOx.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90071/discussion-between-tonkleton-and-iiiiillllllllillllliiiiiiiilll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is an inconsistency between the TFS folder mapping and the local path of the project.

In the `Source Control Explorer`, browse to the folder in question. Look at where it says `Local Path` and ensure it is mapped and has the same relative path described in the error message (which should also be the local project path).